# XCode/iOS/macOS compatibility & upgrading to Catalina

Tags: macos, ios, catalina, xcode, big-sur

I'm trying to use Xcode with my iPhone and it looks like I've updated my iPhone past the point where it's compatible with the version of Xcode that I have.  I made a really simple app that I just want to put on my phone - not putting it on the App Store or anything.  The message I get is:

> **Could not locate device support files.**
>
> This iPhone 6s is running iOS 14.2, which may not be supported
> by this version of Xcode. An updated version of Xcode may be found on
> the App Store or at developer.apple.com.

Here are the versions that I have:

- Xcode - 11.3.1
- macOS - 10.14.6
- iOS - 14.2

The App Store says I need to have at least macOS 10.15.4 to download the latest Xcode.

The upgrade to Big Sur is huge and I'm running fairly low on space on my Mac, so I'd rather just upgrade to Catalina, but I can't seem to find a standalone download (i.e., not an update that requires already having Catalina).  I've tried the link below but I get the error `This update requires macOS version 10.15`.

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2022?locale=en_US

If there's a way I can work around the iOS/Xcode compatibility issue without upgrading Xcode or downgrading iOS, that would be the easiest way to go.  Otherwise, I would need to figure out how to get Catalina as a standalone download.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos - it's getting a bit out of date these days, but I just added the Catalina download link to it.

Comment: I just found it in the App Store a few minutes after posting the question.  For whatever reason, everything out there seems to link to this page https://support.apple.com/downloads/macos rather than the App Store...

Comment: That link is OK for delta or combo updaters, but not for the full OS, which you can *only* get through the App Store. [Delta will go from 15.1 to 15.2 etc, combo will go all the way from 15.0 to 15.5 or whatever is current. Neither will install if you're not already on 15.something - for that you need the App Store.]